# Suddenly YouTube API is not working with exceed qouta

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube data api v3 to get the YouTube video list for many years.

Suddenly YouTube API is not working with 'quotaExceeded'

```
W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
W/System.err: {
W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
W/System.err:     "domain" : "youtube.quota",
W/System.err:     "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
W/System.err:     "reason" : "quotaExceeded"
W/System.err:   } ],
W/System.err:   "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>."
W/System.err: }
```

How can I solve this problem?
Is there any change the YouTube Data API?

Thanks,
Bolero.

Comment: Facing this issue as well. I haven't made an API call since last year but apparently I have exceeded my API limits. Based on what??

Answer (score -1):

The error is exactly what it is. You have exceeded your quota of requests. You need to stop making requests until your quota balance rebuilds. I would recommend implementing a back-off when you receive that quota. You may also want to check your response headers to see if there's something saying how many more calls you can make in that time period.

You could also check your usage in the Google Api Console. Typically inside of your Google Cloud console.

Comment: Not really the problem. Google Api Console shows zero calls made.